how to include import map in JavaScript debugging in Nodel.js?
I'm currently debugging a local Node.js solution and I was wondering, is it possible to add an importmap to Node.js so I can use Import with resource name?
My import map:
<script type="importmap">
{
    "imports": {
        "options": "https://assets.sltech.no/SHARED/JS/OptionsFactory.js",
        "webrequest": "https://assets.sltech.no/SHARED/JS/WebRequest.js",
        "utility": "https://assets.sltech.no/SHARED/JS/Utility.js",
        "logger": "https://assets.sltech.no/SHARED/JS/Logger.js",
        "resources": "https://assets.sltech.no/SHARED/JS/ResourceAccessor.js"
    }
}


Not yet, but there is https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-imports

I am afraid, import map in nodejs are not natively supported yet.
however, you can do this by using alias in your package.json as
npm install module-alias

and detained aliases something like this
"_moduleAliases": {
        "yourAliasesKeyName": "./path/of/your/local/file.js"
//In your case 
        "options": "https://assets.sltech.no/SHARED/JS/OptionsFactory.js",
        "webrequest": "https://assets.sltech.no/SHARED/JS/WebRequest.js",
        "utility": "https://assets.sltech.no/SHARED/JS/Utility.js",
        "logger": "https://assets.sltech.no/SHARED/JS/Logger.js",
        "resources": "https://assets.sltech.no/SHARED/JS/ResourceAccessor.js"
}

after that, you can import the mentioned alias in your code:
import variable from "yourAliasesKeyName";

In your case
import options from 'options'; 


ah great! I had issues with installing module-alias globally, the app found the module-alias module when I used --save.dev. I don't know if that causes any issues? When I tried to use it when installed as in the doc's it couldn't find the module
